# Uncaught exception in try/catch block

Tags: php, exception

A method performs a recursive scan for yaml files and parses them, extracts some of the information. I use sfYamlParser to parse the yaml. I enclosed the call to parse() in a try block and catch "Exception $e" but I still get a "Fatal Error: uncaught exception.

```
try{
    $definition = $parser->parse(file_get_contents($filePath));//line 20
} catch(Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception("Parsing model definiion '$filePath' failed.", 0, $e);
}
```

Snippet from stack trace:

```
...Indexer.php(20): sfYamlParser->parse('type: com...') #3
```

Why is the exception not caught by my catch block?
I did expect the Exception to bubble up and then be caught in my method.
The coe is namespaced but "use Exception" is set.

Error messsage:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unable to parse line 30 (key;          true).' in [...]/packages/fabpot-yaml/sfYamlParser.php:265
Stack trace:
#0 [...]/packages/fabpot-yaml/sfYamlParser.php(201): sfYamlParser-&gt;parse('type:         s...')
#1 [...]/packages/fabpot-yaml/sfYamlParser.php(201): sfYamlParser-&gt;parse('explicitPrivile...')
#2 [...]/packages/hydra/source/com/daliaIT/hydra/Indexer.php(20): sfYamlParser-&gt;parse('type:       com...')
#3 [...]/packages/co3/source/com/daliaIT/co3/PathHelper.php(97): com\daliaIT\hydra\{closure}('packages/hPacks...')
#4 [...]/packages/hydra/source/com/daliaIT/hydra/Indexer.php(28): com\daliaIT\co3\PathHelper-&gt;scanCallback('packages/hPacks...', 'hmd', Object(Closure))
```

**EDIT:**

Ok if I do not throw another exception I get no fatal error. Sorry I expected the code to crash with the error message I defined, not with the original exception messgae, so:

why doesnt it fail with "Parsing model definiion '$filePath' failed."?

**EDIT:**

Turns out PHP has an iteresting way to deal with uncaught exceptions:

If you throw an "new Exception("MESSAGE", 0,$previous_exception)" and do not catch it PHP will display the error message from $previous_exception and NOT "MESSAGE"

Comment: Do you catch the exception that you throw in the catch block specified above?

Comment: What does the rest of the stack trace look like?

Comment: The exception is thrown by "$parser->parse(...)" I want tp catch the exception i throw above but the catch block is never executed.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: If you are sure that it happens in line 20. remove try block and run it again. It'll show you where it occured.

Comment: I do not WANT to know where it occored. i want to re throw with a new message so I throw a new exception message containing the name o the parsed file.

Comment: Maybe it's something with the string repesentation of the exception you are throwing or how you are constructing it (just guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you don't catch the exception you throw in the catch block.

You have to either stop throwing exception again in the catch block, or make a new try catch around / in the calling method.